# Using a button to copy highlighted text to every Combo Box field on form

Tags: ms-access, combobox

In my Form Header, I have a drop down Combo Box and a "Fill All" button.
In my Detail section below the Form Header, I have a series of user accounts, each with their own Combo Box (with the same set of available fields to select as the Combo Box in the header)

After selecting a field in the header to highlight it, I would like to have the ability to click this "Fill All" button to have that text copied to every account's Combo Box.

The current code I have for this "Fill All" button is this:

```
Private Sub Copy_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_cmdCopy_Click

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPaste

Exit_cmdCopy_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdCopy_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdCopy_Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either:
get the selected value, construct a update query, update the records, refresh the form
like:

```
private sub cbo_main_AfterUpdate()
    Dim iVal as string
    ival =  nz(me.cbo_main.value,"")

    dim SQL_SET as string
    sql_set = "update my table set myField='"& iVal &"' Where 'Your where condition'"
    docmd.runSQL sql_set
    me.requery
end Sub
```

**OR**

if its only few combo-boxes just use the after event of your main combo-box to update the "other" combo-boxes.
like:

```
private sub cbo_main_AfterUpdate()
    update_cbo_value nz(me.cbo_main.value,"")
end Sub

private sub update_cbo_value(iVal as string)
    if not ival = "" then
       cbo_1.value = iVal 
       cbo_2.value = iVal 
       cbo_3.value = iVal
    end IF
End Sub
```

Comment: I am having trouble with the part: 

SQL_SET = "update my table set myField='" & iVal & "' Where 'Your where condition'"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL_SET

Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: @tmanbez: sql_set ="..." is sql command to update your table. Docmd.runsql sql_set is command to execute the update operation. check this for mote about update query: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp